# Stack Builder not finding spatial extentions for Postgre 10 when installing PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, installation, windows-server-2012, postgresql-10

I've never set up a development environment on Windows before.

I followed [this guide](http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=postgis_tut01) which is for PostgreSQL 9, but nevertheless. PostGIS is supposed to be installable through Stack Builder, but Stack Builder 4 does not show any Spatial Extensions. I can't find any stand-alone bundles for PostGIS, nor anybody that has the same problem.

When I throw `SELECT AddGeometryColumn('testtable', 'g', 3036, 'POINT', 2)` at my postgre-server it tells me that `addgeometrycolumn()` cannot be found, so I assume that PostGIS is missing.

Any hints as to where to start with this one?

Comment: Sorry everyone. There is a [known problem](http://www.postgis.net/install/) with PostGIS for PostgreSQL 10 which is not yet bundled as of today (nov 2017). In the meanwhile PostgreSQL 9.6 still comes effortlessly with PostGIS (which I went for), but there are unreleased versions available from the [PostGIS download page](http://www.postgis.net/install/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

nJGL yah sorry the folks that manage the Stackbuilder stuff are on vacation I was told.  So issue is still there.  I did upload the exes to Stackbuilder so as soon as the issue is fixed they would show up there.

The stackbuilder will just give you the same installer files you'll find here.

http://winnie.postgis.net/download/windows/pg10/buildbot/

For 64-bit
http://winnie.postgis.net/download/windows/pg10/buildbot/postgis-bundle-pg10x64-setup-2.4.1-1.exe

I haven't packaged pg10 32-bit since I'm having issue with the pointcloud build, hopefully you don't need that.  If you need the 32-bit just use the binaries.

Comment: BTW on stackbuilder now, but to see it requires upgrading to 10.1 and a reboot.

Comment: thanks for the direct path to winnie.postgis.net